# Dynamic data import from folder with csv files

Tags: excel

I have a folder containing several csv files. Is it possible to import the data to a new workbook from each of the files on a separate sheet, without referencing file names? Basically, if the folder contains five csv files named 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, the end result should be a workbook with five sheets named 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 that either reference or copy the data from the csvs. If the file names are different, or of there are more files in the folder, then the workbook should "recognize" that and update the names of the sheets.

I recorded the following macro, manually cycling to some of the files in the folder:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
'
' ImportCSV Macro
'

'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\A17U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "A17U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\A68U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "A68U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\ACV.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "ACV.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\AJBU.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "AJBU.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\AU8U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "AU8U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\AW9U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "AW9U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\C2PU.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "C2PU.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\C38U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "C38U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\manuel\Documents\Projects (current)\Finanzen, Investments\Singapore REIT\Quotes\Current\C61U.SI.csv" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "C61U.SI"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This is cumbersome, and I am sure it can be automated to cycle through the folder and find all files in it by itself.

Also, the macro should rename the sheets that it imports the data into with the filename of the csv file. This would be a huge time saver. Many thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Yes it is using VBA, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "extract data from all files in a folder"? the first 8 listed for me are SE links!